Nav2 distance traveled condition
I'm looking at this code (Humble branch):
https://github.com/ros-navigation/navigation2/blob/humble/nav2_behavior_tree/plugins/condition/distance_traveled_condition.cpp
I don't think this works or maybe I'm missing something obvious.
Conceptually this is my understanding:

When the behavior tree is first loaded, all nodes are in the IDLE state before they are ticked for the first time
tick() method here first checks for IDLE status, in which case it gets the start_pose_
immediately returns FAILURE

I don't see anything setting the status different than IDLE, so how does this condition plugin ever exits the initial IDLE status check?

@steve-macenski any insights?
